# how to get consol output as csv

Tags: python-3.x, web, web-scraping

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import flickrapi
import xml
api_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
api_secret ='xxxxxxxxxxxx'

flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key,secret=api_secret)
r = flickr.photos_search(advanced= '1&text=agriculture%20%20south%20africa', has_geo="1", per_page='1')
a=ET.tostring(r)
print(str(a))

with open('farms.docx', 'w',newline='') as f:
    print('a', a, file=f)
```

i have this output in my python shell how can i only print the value of id in the csv file

```
b'<rsp stat="ok">\n<photos page="1" pages="34486" perpage="10" total="344856">\n\t<photo farm="66" id="49560152912" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" owner="97099263@N03" secret="a331bfa2a0" server="65535" title="ha_2020-02-20-1600" />\n\t<photo farm="66" id="49559914451" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" owner="97099263@N03" secret="02c4fd38c6" server="65535" title="wh_2020-02-20-1600" />\n\t<photo farm="66" id="49559914351" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" owner="69506664@N06" secret="ffe5ddcfe1" server="65535" title="2020-01-22_13-01-20_ILCE-6500_DSC08328_DxO" />\n\t<photo farm="66" id="49559913241" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" owner="150156215@N05" secret="de69ab61f1" server="65535" title="JOB-451" />\n\t<photo farm="66" id="49559417633" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" owner="150156215@N05" secret="12da8bd740" server="65535" title="JOM-903" />\n\t<photo farm="66" id="49559912936" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" owner="69506664@N06" secret="d7a95cf7f4" server="65535" title="2020-01-22_13-01-08_ILCE-6500_DSC08325_DxO" />\n\t<photo farm="66" id="49560151342" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" owner="69506664@N06" secret="00c2f047a0" server="65535" title="2020-01-22_12-57-04_ILCE-6500_DSC08297_DxO" />\n\t<photo farm="66" id="49560151272" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" owner="153308157@N06" secret="2ff11eacd7" server="65535" title="Anole" />\n\t<photo farm="66" id="49559417108" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" owner="40103142@N07" secret="90732e6b57" server="65535" title="FlowingWater" />\n\t<photo farm="66" id="49559417018" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" owner="69506664@N06" secret="a49159382b" server="65535" title="2020-01-22_12-58-23_ILCE-6500_DSC08308_DxO" />\n</photos>\n</rsp>'
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty simple, so try modifying your code along these lines:

```
my_str = """
<rsp stat="ok">\n<photos page="1" pages="349322" perpage="1" total="349322">\n\t<photo farm="66" id="49556518667" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" owner="36925516@N05" secret="25b43dbf77" server="65535" title="Petra Royal Tombs" />\n</photos>\n</rsp>
"""

target = etree.fromstring(my_str)
target.xpath('//@id')
```

Output:

> ['49556518667']